# Issue when Trying to Fire a ASP.NET Custom Control Button Event

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls

I have a simple asp.net test custom control that I have created and am trying to figure out why the click event will not fire. Below is the code. I simply create an instance of the control on a test page with `Page_Load` of .aspx page that consumes the control `protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { Page.Form.Controls.Add(new TestControl()); }`

The page does a post back but it does not pick up the click event in the user control. Please explain what I am doing incorrectly or a better way to approach this with a specific pattern etc.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace WorldOfTest
{
    public class TestControl : WebControl { private Button btn;
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {            
        base.OnInit(e);
    }

    protected override void EnsureChildControls()
    {
        btn = new Button();           
        this.Controls.Add(btn); 
        base.EnsureChildControls();
    }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {

        btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);  
        btn.Text = "test button";                         
        base.CreateChildControls();
    }

    void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        btn.RenderControl(writer); ;
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: I would use this.Controls.Add(new TestControl()); instead in your page load. Page.Form.Controls is weird

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding your custom control to the page use LoadControl.

```
var control = (TestControl)LoadControl("~/path/to/TestControl.ascx");
Page.Form.Controls.Add(control);
```

Comment: It's a WebControl, not the UserControl

Comment: Hi WDuffy,Thanks for your prompt  reply.but my issue is I am using custom control...

Answer (score 0):

If your button is in the control collection, you don't need to override render and call btn.Render. I would also add it and subscribe to the event OnLoad. One last thing, You need to implement INamingContainer.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
   btn = new Button();
   btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);  
   btn.Text = "test button";
   this.Controls.Add(btn);
}
```